# Custom skinned facebook like button using javascript SDK

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a custom image which I would like to use rather than the standard facebook like styled one. I have this working but it only 'shares' the page rather than 'liking' it.

I was wondering if there was a way to use jQuery or javascript SDK to make this button 'like' the page as I don't agree with using CSS to 'mask' the standard button?

Its a pitty its not a simple as twitters API to make a custom button...

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes) but the problem is that you'd need to create an app and then get the user the allow that app to publish to their stream. A lot of faff in my opinion.

My understanding of why it's like this is because if one could programme it without the user authing the application then that application can spam a load of users into liking stuff they didn't like.

Answer (score 1):

In general the icon for the facebook like icon is contained into :

```
.connect_widget_like_button .liketext
```

So you could override the css using :

```
.connect_widget_like_button .liketext {background-image : url('path_of_my_customized_image.jpg') !important;}
```

Using the `!important` will force the css to ovveride it to your settings even if the css for the facebook like icon is loaded after this piece of code ;)

Hope it helps ;)

**EDIT :** Using this in JQuery is easy too, just write :

```
$('.connect_widget_like_button .liketext').css('background-image', "url('path_of_my_customized_image.jpg') !important;");
```

Comment: Do we have to call this jquery inside a function the iframe has loaded right? I am trying something like that but the like button still doesn't change a bit. I am calling the jquery inside a function which I am calling in the $('iframe').load(function(){}); function. Any suggestions as to where I am making the mistake?

Comment: I have tried that too. I also noticed that fb's like button's span,div tags have their style attributes in the tag. I think since that will override any other styling information specified I suppose that is the reason I am not able see anything...

Comment: Did you use the keyword `!important` ?

Comment: If it is in the tag attributes, you can try to overload these attributes using `.attr()`. Example for changing width : `$('selector').attr('width', '100%')`